# Using libraries in vscode

Tags: c++, json, opencv, compiler-errors, linker

I want to use the OpenCV library for c++ in vscode and do not really understand how I can make it work.
I wrote the following short piece of code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main(){
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("test.jpeg");
}
```

My first approach was, to download OpenCV by using homebrew and then moving the downloaded opencv folder to /usr/local/include. After that, I was able to use #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp> without any error messages. However, after compiling the program, I now get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "cv::Mat::~Mat()", referenced from:
      _main in test-d4f31f.o
  "cv::imread(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int)", referenced from:
      _main in test-d4f31f.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have looked for the reason of this error and apparently the linker does not link the header file with the main file containing the piece of code above. I then figured out, that apparently moving a library folder to /usr/local/include is not the right way to use a library, and instead I should give the compiler the path to the library in the tasks.json file. Mine currently looks like this:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ Aktive Datei kompilieren",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "Vom Debugger generierte Aufgabe."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Now I don't now how to proceed, how to give the compiler the correct instruction and even if this is the correct way to do it. I would be glad if someone could give me a detailed answer

Comment: OpenCV should include some `lib??.a` or `lib??.so` files, which need to be linked using `-l??` (the flag has to be after the source file name, not before).

Comment: Moving downloaded libraries manually looks unwise. You should keep them in the original location and use `-I` and `-L` to point the compiler to the directories with `.h` and `.a`/`.so` files respectively.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat the downloaded folder contains .hpp files, lib??.a files and .dylib files. Which of them should I use and what is the difference between them ?

Comment: Copy all of them, and `-l??` should pick either `lib??.a` or `lib??.dylib` (probably the latter by default). Those are probably for static and dynamic linking respectively (look those terms up), but I don't have much experience with MacOS.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Wow thanks it works now! But let's say I write a program that would use 50 of these lib??.a files and I don't want to link all 50 in a long command, is there an easier way?

Comment: You have to state every library you're using, so either way you're gonna have 50 of something. But you can look into build systems, such as Make (with pkg-config), CMake.